# Why is my programmatic screenshot capturing out of date view?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a map view that allows users to draw perimeter lines, and I need to capture a screenshot when they are done to save for recording purposes. For some reason, my code is capturing the view state before the new overlay is added, even though I add the overlay before attempting the screenshot.

I use a separate view to capture gesture, and then covert the points to an overlay and add it to the map here where `points` are the points gathered from the gesture tracking

```
func convertFragments() {
        var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
        for point in points {
            let coordinate = mapView.convert(point, toCoordinateFrom: drawingView)
            coordinates.append(coordinate)
        }
        let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
        polyline.title = selectedTool.name
        removeLines(for: selectedTool)
        points = []
        mapView.addOverlay(polyline)
        incidentManager.update(for: selectedTool, value: polyline)
    }
```

Then `incidentManager.update(value: polyline)` makes a network call to save the information and calls a second method to capture the screenshot and update a log in `log(eventType: eventType)`

```
func update(for tool: MapTool, value: Any) {
        func saveLine(_ line: MKPolyline, for key: String) {
            incidentReference.setData([
                key: IncidentManager.convertCLPoints(line.coordinates)
            ], merge: true)
        }
        switch tool {
        case .hotZone, .innerPerimeter, .outerPerimeter:
            let line = value as! MKPolyline
            saveLine(line, for: tool.rawValue)
        case .commandPost, .stagingArea:
            let point = value as! CLLocationCoordinate2D
            let geoPoint = GeoPoint(latitude: point.latitude, longitude: point.longitude)
            incidentReference.setData([
                tool.rawValue: geoPoint
            ], merge: true)
        case .poi:
            let annotation = value as! PerimeterMapAnnotation
            let point = annotation.coordinate
            let geoPoint = GeoPoint(latitude: point.latitude, longitude: point.longitude)
            incidentReference.setData([
                "pointsOfInterest": [annotation.title: geoPoint]
            ], merge: true)
        default:
            return
        }

        updateAddress(defaultValue: value)

        let eventType = tool.eventType(didSet: true)
        log(eventType: eventType)
    }
```

I have an extension on `UIView` that captures the view, but for some reason, its not the most updated version of the map view.

```
private func log(eventType: LogEventType) {
        guard let mapImage = mapView.asImage() else { return }
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
        let imageRef = storageRef.child("\(incident.id)/\(UUID().uuidString).jpg")
        let eventTime = Date()
        let eventTimeString = eventTime.apiDateString
        incidentReference.collection("eventLog").document(eventTimeString).setData([
            "logEventType": eventType.rawValue,
            "imageReference": imageRef.fullPath,
            "date": Timestamp(date: eventTime)
        ])

        upload(image: mapImage, at: imageRef)

        if shouldUpdateCover {
            shouldUpdateCover = false
            incidentReference.setData([
                "coverPhotoRef": imageRef.fullPath
            ], merge: true)
        }
    }
```

```
func asImage() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.isOpaque, 0.0)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            self.layer.render(in: context)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            return image
        }
        return nil
}
```

I have tried many variations this "screenshot" method that I have found online, and no luck. When I debug, I can check the map and its overlays, and see that they are updating before hand.

Any ideas why the image captured here does not capture the changes made?

Comment: show us the code for `incidentManager.update(value: polyline)` and how you update your map

Comment: Where are you writing code?  Where does a guy named 'incidentManager' come from?  Why does the first section of your code doesn't start with the open bracket but ends with the closed bracket?

Comment: Where is the guy named 'asImage' being used?

Comment: @workingdog I added the code for the `incidentManager.update(value: polyline)` A lot of it is irrelevant for this issue. Specifically I'm concerned with the functionality in `func log(eventType: LogEventType)`

Comment: @ElTomato The `convertFragments` lives in a view controller that holds the MKMapView `mapView`. This view controller also holds an instance of a helper class `IncidentManager` and that class holds the other methods shared here. IncidentManager holds a reference to the mapView and that's how it gets the image. Its not the best to have the reference but its the cleanest way I could save these logs. `asImage` is used in the `log(eventType: LogEventType)` method